# Problems importing To Excel a HTML file With Multiple Css Classes On Elements

Tags: css, excel

Excel looks that it does not understand the HTML attribute 'class' if several CSS classes are pointed for HTML element.

For example if "class='A B'" pointed to tag 'TD' Excel will use empty style for the tag.

I have these html code:

```
<style type="text/css">
TABLE.t1_table{
background-color:#828a3c;
border:solid 1px #3A6EA5;
padding-left:2px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-right:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
font-style:italic;
font-variant:small-caps;
font-size:20px;
color:#6b3f07;
border-collapse:collapse;
```

}

```
TR.t1_ph TD{
background-color:#B0C4DE;
border:solid 1px #3A6EA5;
padding-right:6px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#3A6EA5;
```

}

```
TR.t1_co TD{
background-color:#103a70;
border:solid 1px #3A6EA5;
padding-right:6px;
```

}

```
</style>

<table class="t1_table" cellpadding="" cellspacing="">
<tr class="t1_ph"><td colspan="1">Age</td></tr>
<tr class="t1_co"><td style="background-color:#cb7878">45</td></tr>
<tr class="t1_co"><td>23</td></tr>
</table>
```

If I open the file in IE, then I can see correctly.
If I open the file in MS Excel, then I see wrong.

It this a a known problem in Office?

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Same here, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823531/css-style-class-not-combining-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Excell is not an internet browser and do not expect it to parse css, it will use only element containing classes, so you need to use this kind of code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.t1_table {
    background-color:#828a3c;
    border:solid 1px #3A6EA5;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#6b3f07;
    border-collapse:collapse;   
}

.t1_ph {
    background-color:green;
    border:solid 1px #3A6EA5;
    padding-right:6px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#3A6EA5;  
}

.t1_co {
    background-color:red;
    border:solid 1px #3A6EA5;
    padding-right:6px;  

}

</style>

<table class="t1_table" cellpadding="" cellspacing="">
    <tr><td class="t1_ph">Age</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="t1_co" style="background-color:#cb7878">45</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="t1_co">23</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is also good, because sometimes you need to define Excell cell-type and you can use following formats: http://cosicimiento.blogspot.co.at/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html