# CSS style class not combining in Excel

Tags: html, css, excel

Why isn't Excel combining these styles?

> Excel:
>
> [image]
>
> IE:
>
> [image]

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RtJj/

HTML source:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.greenBack{background-color:#d7e4bc}
.redFont{color:red}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>no style</td><td class="redFont">red font only</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="greenBack">green back only</td><td class="redFont greenBack">green back and red font</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but possibly because Excel isn't equipped to import more complex CSS stuff. (Or it's that IE6 bug that honours only the first CSS class when multiple ones are specified - maybe Excel's HTML parser has the same issue)

Comment: `greenBack` and `redFont` are **REALLY** bad names for CSS classes. Use semantic classes like `important` and `info` so you can change the look without changing the semantic meaning

Comment: How does MS Word render it? I'm assuming that it's the Word HTML parser/renderer rather than the IE engine that's being used in Office?

Comment: @Pekka The problem in IE 6 is when you have a CSS selectors like `redFont.greenBack`, not when you apply `class="redFont greenBack"`

Comment: That html isn't what is forming the output on the picture, the text is different

Comment: @Juan Mendes, define "bad names". I wouldn't use it for my real code, but I thought it made the example clear.

Comment: @Juan ahh, you're right, I misremembered.

Comment: @Andy I updated the HTML source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone had a similar problem [Here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/373475-html-imported-to-excel-with-multiple-css-classes-on-elements.html). It seems as if excel only supports having one class, and if there is more it just ignores them all together. I would recommend having a greenBackRedFont class that sets both properties.

Answer (score 0):

*normly
"'  p style="text-align: center"

In excel write formula like this:
"'="p style=""text-align: center""  xxx*

"
 (") 2 times write("")
Than you copy paste same