# How Can I Apply More than One Class per Element for HTML that Is to Be Read in Excel?

Tags: html, css, excel

In standard HTML, of course, an element can be associated with more than one class simply by putting a space between the class names.

Microsoft Excel can read plain HTML (a function that is essential to a long-standing report I am trying to modify) -- but it appears that Excel ignores class information if more than one class is applied to an element.

My actual situation is pretty complex -- but the following simplified example will illustrate the problem: If the following text is saved with a `.xls` extension, it will load in Excel.

```
<style>
    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
    .italic { font-style: italic; }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bold">This will display in bold.</td>
        <td class="italic">This will display in italics.</td>
        <td class="bold italic">This should display bold italics, but it doesn't.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it looks like this:

[image: Screen shot of the above as displayed in Excel]

(Saved as `.htm`, the same content loads in a web browser and displays as expected.)

I haven't been able to find any mention of this behavior in web searches or searches for similar questions here, but I *have* experimented with a few non-standard ways of listing the classes just to see if Excel would interpret them both, including the following:

- `<td class="bold" class="italic">` (multiple `class` attributes)
- `<td class="bold,italic">` (comma-separated)
- `<td class="bold;italic">` (semicolon-separated)
- `<td class="bold|italic">` (pipe-separated)

Unsurprisingly, none of these worked. Is there some way/trick/hack to make Excel recognize multiple classes when it loads a file in HTML format? Or is this just something that the program is inherently unable to handle?

Comment: Can try using the depreciated `<b><i>` tags.Or `<td style: "font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">`

Comment: Thanks, but my example above is a very simplified version of the real scenario, which involves borders, shading, etc.. I _have_ been using `style="..."`, but it's cumbersome and hard-to-manage. I asked this question in the hope of finding a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to create an additional class that contains both styles.

```
<style>
    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
    .italic { font-style: italic; }
    .bold-italic { font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bold">This will display in bold.</td>
        <td class="italic">This will display in italics.</td>
        <td class="bold-italic">This will display in bold and italics.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done this a bit -- but my real-world situation is more complex than the simplified example I put on here to illustrate the problem. I've upvoted your answer because it certainly does work -- but I'm hoping there's a solution that will allow me to combine styles.

Comment: @JoeDeRose based on some other similar stackoverflow questions, it sounds like others have had the same problem and not figured it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823531/css-style-class-not-combining-in-excel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823531/css-style-class-not-combining-in-excel. You might be able to use a CSS pre-processor or a tool aimed at creating HTML emails to inline your styles automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Sanders. (And apologies for the duplicate question; unless I completely overlooked it, that one didn't pop up in either my independent searches or in Stack Overflow's suggestions.)