# Telerik format Export Excel cell

Tags: excel, telerik, export

I faced on an issue with a export to Excel from a Telerik Radgrid.

The result is set like this in my column:

```
03RD
04RT
345
```

For the third value, I have in database 0345. 
I bet on an Excel reformating and considering my data as a number and not a varchar (My column in database is a varchar).

Do you know how i can reforge my result as a varchar and to be displayed like this

```
03RD
04RT
0345
```

I read all the documention provided by Telerik and the only thing I got is ExportFormating with several attributes and no one matches my needs.

Comment: I know nothing about telerik, but, in general, if the data is in some kind of TEXT file, you can **IMPORT** the file so that the Text Import Wizard opens; then designate that column as "Text". Another option, if possible, tell telerik to precede varchar with a single quote.  Excel will then interpret as text; the single quote will show up in the formula bar but not in the cell itself, and not in any printouts.

Comment: You could use styles on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872253/problems-importing-to-excel-a-html-file-with-multiple-css-classes-on-elements.

Comment: You could use styles on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872253/problems-importing-to-excel-a-html-file-with-multiple-css-classes-on-elements.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution may be to wrap the cell contents with &nbsp tags.

aspx:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataFormatString="&nbsp;{0}" DataField="Id"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

cs:

```
foreach (GridTableCell gcell in e.Item.Cells) 
gcell.Text = String.Format("&nbsp;{0}", gcell.Text);
```

If that doesn't work then you can try this:

```
protected void RadGrid1_GridExporting(object source, GridExportingArgs e)
{
  e.ExportOutput = e.ExportOutput.Replace("\"0", "=\"0");
}
```